# How to configure a different Saml2SecurityTokenHandler for passive federation in ADFS 2.0 .net 3.5

Tags: adfs

How do I configure an other Saml2SecurityTokenHandler (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler) class for my passive federation on my ADFS 2.0 server?

Right now: i'm trying the folowing configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
<section name="microsoft.identityModel" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.MicrosoftIdentityModelSection, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
   ...
  </configSections>
  <microsoft.identityModel>
    <service>       
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <remove type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <remove type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml11.Saml11SecurityTokenHandler, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add type="ClassLibrary1.Class1, ClassLibrary1" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
    </service>
  </microsoft.identityModel>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Removing the <remove> elements result in an exception on ADFS 2.0 Windows Service startup (an item with the same key has already been added) so we know for sure our configuration is succesfully loaded. But when using passive federation we see that the default MSISSaml2TokenHandler is still used:

> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException: MSIS3120:
>   SubjectConfirmationData had wrong recipient. Expected
>   'https://secure.mydomain.com/adfs/ls/' but received :
>   'https://secure.proxy.mydomain.com/adfs/ls/'.
>     at **Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.MSISSaml2TokenHandler**.ValidateConfirmationData(Saml2SubjectConfirmationData confirmationData)

When reading the msdn documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg638730.aspx) it seems to be configured as it should be. <service> element without a name is a default configuration and is to be used in passive federation scenario's.

Please help me! This is the last hurdle of weeks of work..